# Dependency included in project despite not appearing in maven dependency tree

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project with a dependency conflict in the AWS SDK. After building the artifact I have `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar` and `aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar` (which is included explicitly) included. I ran `mvn dependency:tree` to find out which component is pulling in the older version of the SDK (1.7.4) but it doesn't appear anywhere. I'm almost sure that the responsible component is `hadoop-client` but I don't understand why AWS SDK 1.7.4 gets bundled into the artifact despite not appearing in the dependency tree. What's going on here?

Comment: Are you build a war or ear? Or are you building a fat jar/uber-jar?

Comment: I'm building a .war file.

Comment: I assume you are running `mvn dependency:tree` on the war project, did a `clean` before building the war and didn't tamper with the settings (e.g. what to clean, how to build the war, etc.) - am I right here? Especially in the latter case we'd need to see your pom.xml. Also try adding `-Dverbose` to `dependency:tree`.

Comment: Yep. But unfortunately I can't show the `pom.xml`. I know it's problematic but it belongs to my employer.

Comment: Did you go through the logs to find where the artifact gets included?

Comment: Yes, I know which projects include the old AWS SDK. I suppose I could go and add an exclusion in each one but I wonder why it's not showing up in the dependency tree in the first place.

Comment: Just to make sure: You really called all these commands from the command line, you are not looking at it through an IDE? Do the poms which have a dependency on AWS SDK contain anything special?

Comment: Yep, I did call all of them from the command line. Regarding the poms, nothing special that I'm aware of. I'm almost sure that the dependency on hadoop-client is what's causing AWS SDK to get pulled in, despite a specific `exclusion` directive. I'm just not sure how this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know these issues only from cases where the workspace was not properly cleaned (i.e. using `clean`).

Comment: I did run `clean` and even manually deleted the old AWS SDK from `~/.m2/repository`.